# KB Patch Install on multiple servers

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to install KB patch on multiple server , but i am getting below error message while executing. Can someone please help me with this?

FYI : PSRemoting is enabled on the system

Code:

```
$SB={ Start-Process -FilePath 'wusa.exe' -ArgumentList "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu /quiet /norestart" -Wait -PassThru }


Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer -ScriptBlock $SB
```

Error :

```
[computer] Connecting to remote server computer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer computer. Verify
that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (computer:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
[computer] Connecting to remote server computer failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the
request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer computer. Verify
that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For more information, see the
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (computer:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: Is the target computer in the same domain as the one sending the request?  If not, then it can't use Kerberos authentication.  You should check out the [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6) help topic that the error recommends and make sure everything is set up ok (just enabling remoting isn't always enough).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to run the script on workgroup computers if am i right, When you are running the script on workgroup machines you have to set below commands on each and every server before you run the script

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Set-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts *
Restart-Service WinRM
Test-WsMan <server name>
```

Comment: Is that server part of domain ?

Comment: servers are in same domain. but still i am facing this issue.